# How to display several employees from mysql on the my index.html?

Tags: python, django

Code for index in views.py

```
def index(request):
employees = Employee.objects.all()
schedules = []

for e in employees:

    s = Schedule.objects.filter(employee_id=e.employee_id, is_active=1)

    if (s.count() > 0):
        data = {}
        data['employee_id'] = e.employee_id
        data['schedule'] = s
        schedules.append(data)

context = {
    "employees": employees,
    "schedules": schedules
}

print(request.user.username)
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Hmtl of Index

```
 <div class="col-md-3 parent">
<div class="card card-profile">
  <div class="card-avatar">
    <a href="#pablo">
      <img class="img" src="{% static 'img/faces/marc.jpg' %}">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-category text-gray">{{ employee.job_title.job_title }}</h5>
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ employee.first_name }}  {{ employee.last_name }}</h4>
      <h6 class="card-category text-gray">ILO - {{ employee.employee_id }}</h6>
      <h6 class="card-category text-gray">HOME HEALTH</h6>
    <p class="card-description" style="font-weight:bold">
```

My problem is i have several employees on mysql database and i wanted to show those employees
 on the [Index Page](https://www.screencast.com/t/pYpNJmd0), right now only one employee showing up. Thanks if for the help.

Comment: You must loop over the`employees` variable in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use loop over the employee in template

```
<div class="col-md-3 parent">
<div class="card card-profile">
  <div class="card-avatar">
    <a href="#pablo">
      <img class="img" src="{% static 'img/faces/marc.jpg' %}">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    {% for employee in employees %}
    <h5 class="card-category text-gray">{{ employee.job_title.job_title }}</h5>
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ employee.first_name }}  {{ employee.last_name }}</h4>
      <h6 class="card-category text-gray">ILO - {{ employee.employee_id }}</h6>
      <h6 class="card-category text-gray">HOME HEALTH</h6>
    {% endfor %}
    <p class="card-description" style="font-weight:bold">
```